# Tourist Visa to Australia

Tags: visas, australia, applications

My husband and I plan to go Australia . I am working in Singapore and he is in the Philippines.

Can I apply for our visa together online?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply separately but your applications can be processed together.

The Australian government's [Visitor visa page](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/sponsored-family-stream#About) states:

> ## Include family
>
> You can't include family members in your application. A separate application must be made for each member of your family, including those listed on your passport.
>
> If other family members are applying for this visa, your applications can be processed together. Learn more when you apply for the visa.

Comment: *your applications can be processed together* Does this apply even when applying in different countries (which I think is the crux of the question)?